# Some pdf attachments showed as octet-stream in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my ASP.NET MVC web application, I have given the option to users to attached `PDF` files or `JPEG` files in the view.

So once the user uploads the file I'm `saving` those files by considering `file type`.

The issue is I got complaints that some attachments can't view the other user. So I checked the database and the `PDF`files attached by some users not passed to the database but the `file type` it shows as `octet-stream`

This is how it stored in the database

[image]

This is how my code in the controller

```
foreach(PurchasingItems item in appRequest.PurchasingItemsList) 
{
  HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["ImageData" + item.TempID];
  item.Attachment = ConvertToBytes(file);
  item.FileType = Path.GetFileName(file.ContentType);
}

public byte[] ConvertToBytes(HttpPostedFileBase image) {

  byte[] imageBytes = null;
  using(BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(image.InputStream)) {
    imageBytes = br.ReadBytes(image.ContentLength);
  }

  return imageBytes;
}
```

Since the system is almost live I need to overcome with a solution to resolve this as soon as possible. So anyone knows what is the issue here and how to solve it?

Comment: `file.ContentType` holds the MIME type, you can't parse that into `Path.GetFileName`

Comment: @DavidG Thanks for the relpy. Is that so ? So how to avoid this?

Comment: Well I would guess you should use `file.FileName` instead.

Comment: @DavidG I will try this. Also, I have no idea why Is the file won't update that related to the ``octet-stream`` file types.